# Is moving to the next phase done manually, or does it happen automatically after some time?

Tags: support, area-51, site-lifecycle

Currently the [Pro Webmasters](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters) Proposal on Area51 has enough to go to the Commitment Phase, yet is still in the Definition Phase.

Is moving to he next phase done manually or does it happen automatically after some time (for example, once a day)?

Comment: Perhaps there's a delay - i.e. it has to stay at the threshold for [n] days to cope with followers dropping out or on/off topic votes changing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The process of transitioning sites from Definition to Commit is still manual. [David](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146719/david-fullerton) is going to automate the process, if not today, very soon.

[Pro Webmasters](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters) has been advanced to the Commit phase. Enjoy.

**EDIT**

This has now been fully automated!

Comment: It's automated now!

Comment: @emmett Is it working?  Personal Finance has met it's requirements but hasn't moved yet.

Comment: @emmett Nvm, moved now.