# Is going from phase to phase automatic on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is moving to the next phase done manually, or does it happen automatically after some time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-moving-to-the-next-phase-done-manually-or-does-it-happen-automatically-after)

I've been following [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/894/pro-webmasters) with some interest. For the better part of a day, it sat needing 0 on/off topic questions and 0 followers.

Is advancing to the next phase a manual process, or was it hung on a fraction of 1 in regards to needed questions, which was rounded up to 0 for display?

This isn't a bug or anything. I'm just curious and rather compulsive when it comes to details.

Had I actually owned the proposal, this question would have been more like "My proposal satisfied the definition phase, why can't I commit to it?"

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-moving-to-the-next-phase-done-manually-or-does-it-happen-automatically-after ... which is actually about the very same proposal, go figure...

Comment: Yikes, did not see that, voted to close this.