# How often do sites move into the commit phase?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is moving to the next phase done manually, or does it happen automatically after some time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-moving-to-the-next-phase-done-manually-or-does-it-happen-automatically-after)

How often do sites move into the commit phase?  I just noticed that [Personal Finance and Money](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) has met it's criteria for commitment phase, but I don't yet have an option to commit.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-moving-to-the-next-phase-done-manually-or-does-it-happen-automatically-after

Comment: Personal Finance and Money has apparently now been moved to the commit phase

Answer (score 2):

It used to be handled manually by a moderator, but supposedly yesterday an [automated solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-moving-to-the-next-phase-done-manually-or-does-it-happen-automatically-after/53866#53866) was rolled out, so I would expect it to happen as soon as the definition requirements are set. I have no experience with it though, there may be an intentional delay for some reason

Comment: I would say there's a delay just to make sure that the number of followers is stable, and that the on- and off-topic questions have settled down too.

Comment: @ChrisF Is that a guess or knowledge?

Comment: @C. Ross - a guess, but it's what I'd do.