# Why Writing proposal is not entering Commitment phase?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase

Currently the [Writing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writing) proposal on Area 51 is *Definition*, and to to move to the next phase it needs:

- 0 followers
- 0 on-topic questions
- 0 off-topic questions

So... why is blocked in Definition and does not automatically enter Commitment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is moving to the next phase done manually, or does it happen automatically after some time?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-moving-to-the-next-phase-done-manually-or-does-it-happen-automatically-after)

Comment: @ChrisF: but in that question, emmett said that the process is now automated...

Comment: Now is in Commitment

Comment: See my comment to that question - I suspect there is a delay built into the process.

Comment: @ChrisF: I see, however it is not a good idea show to the user the box "it needs 0 actions to move to the next phase" (the user will think "WTF?"). It would be better something like "soon will enter Commitment phase".

Comment: @Lorenzo - you're right there. It would be better.

Comment: Please see my answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55720/why-writing-proposal-is-not-entering-commitment-phase/55786#55786

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should always happen immediately now.

I believe the bug was that if a proposal got its last follower after someone verified their email address (since followers without verified email addresses aren't counted) then the proposal didn't move into commitment properly.  This has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The process was [apparently made automated to some degree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-moving-to-the-next-phase-done-manually-or-does-it-happen-automatically-after). However, as you can see in the comments on the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-moving-to-the-next-phase-done-manually-or-does-it-happen-automatically-after/53866#53866), it's not necessarily immediate or in a predictable schedule.

Please wait warmly until it is committed. If it takes longer than a day, then maybe a manual look will be necessary.

Comment: Actually, it should have happened immediately.  See my answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55720/why-writing-proposal-is-not-entering-commitment-phase/55786#55786

Answer (score 0):

I think that has to be done manually - it was the same for the web application proposal.

Comment: Really? Manually? That's a bit weird!

Comment: @lorenzo - the engine is in beta, as well as the sites it creates...

Comment: @Antony: if it supposed to be automatic and it does not work then well, it is in beta. But if it is not supposed to be automatic then it is weird!