# Why has the Chinese proposal not moved into Commitment phase automatically

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

According to a mods answer in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55720/why-writing-proposal-is-not-entering-commitment-phase/55786#55786), a proposal should move automatically into the Commitment phase.

Is this answer now incorrect or is this a bug? The [Chinese language proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388/chinese-language) is also waiting on 0 of everything.

Answer (score 1):

The [Chinese language proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388/chinese-language) is in commitment now—sometimes things lag a little, and I've found it helps to vote on some more questions.

You said that the Chinese language proposal is *also* waiting—is there another stuck proposal?

Comment: I used _also_ because it was in the same situation as the question linked. In David's answer he said it should happen immediately, but in this case it took almost 24 hours. I know because I was the person who added the 20th vote to the last question.